# How to intialize an array list?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm writing this code where I can add an object (PhoneNumber) to an array of objects, (PhoneNumberList). What I'm confused about is how would I initialize the PhoneNumberList constructor?

So if I want to add a PhoneNumber to the PhoneNumberList, how should I initialize the PhoneNumberList()?

```
public class PhoneNumberList {
    private PhoneNumber[]   storage;
    private static final int INITIAL_SIZE = 2;

    // Purpose:
    // Initialize a new instance of PhoneNumberList

    public PhoneNumberList() {
         storage = new PhoneNumber[INITIAL_SIZE];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

u can set  storage [0]=xxx storage[1]=xxxx
OR storage = new PhoneNumber[]{xxx,yyy};